XPC Service always falling into invalidationHandler despite proper configuration
I have configured an XPC service in my macOS application, and I've ensured that the service is set up correctly. However, whenever I try to establish a connection between my app and the XPC service, it always falls into the invalidationHandler block, indicating that the connection is being invalidated.
I just want to test if the connection works at the moment, so I'm not concerned about specific functionality. I've checked my XPC service configuration, and everything seems to be in place.
Here's a simplified version of my code, and some pictures that I provide for my setup of my project :




I'm struggling to figure out why the connection is being invalidated despite the proper configuration. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
